# Failling to obtain all the solutions [findall + minimal solutions]

Tags: prolog

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/projetmbc/410d8d8ed71b5d1de132d861c2bdaa05) shows a code looking for some special paths. It finds all the legal paths but it fails to find all the best ones: I would like to obtain `[1, 2, 3, 3]` , `[2, 2, 3, 3]` and `[5, 4, 3, 3` but only the 1st path is returned.

What have I missed?

Comment: BTW, if you're using SWI-Prolog, you might be interesting in tabled execution (SLG resolution) and minimum solutions (https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=tabling-mode-directed)

Also, https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate

Comment: @PeterLudemann I would like to "do all by hands" but I will play with your links also. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is generate all solutions and then sort them. And to take advantage of the built-in predicates, do it like this, generate the items as `Cost-Path` rather than your form (which I think is `[Path,Cost]`.

So, something like this:

```
    findall(Total-NbCols,
            onepath(Grid, NbCols, Total),
            AllPaths),
    keysort(AllPaths, [Cost-Path|_]).
```

If there are multiple paths with the same minimum cost, this only gives one of them. If you want all for that minimum cost:

```
solution(Paths, Cost):-
    Grid = [
        [1, 1, 4, 5, 2, 1, 2],
        [3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 0],
        [3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 2, 4],
        [3, 7, 1, 2, 5, 8, 5]
    ],
    findall(Total-NbCols,
            onepath(Grid, NbCols, Total),
            AllPaths),
    keysort(AllPaths, [Cost-_|_]),
    convlist(eq_cost(Cost), AllPaths, Paths).
```

Except setof/3 will do the sorting for you. I leave that as trivial an exercise (you can do nested setof's).

Comment: The predicate `eq_cost(Cost, X-Path, Path):-X = Cost.` is missing. No?